# Perserving File Ownership Win7 Share

Tags: windows, file-ownership

I am trying to setup a "dropbox" on a Win7 workstation we will use to process simulation jobs. My plan was to pull ownership from file (do a simple dir /q "filename") so I can use the owner information during the simulation (send them an email when done for example).

The problem I have is when the user drops the simulation file on the share I setup, the ownership is set to BUILTIN\Administrators. I have tried tweak the share settings but so far nothing seems to work.

I do have a work around where users can embed their email address in the simulation file and I could pull that. But trying to make it easier as I know somer user will forget to do that... Any ideas how to preserver the ownership inforamation?

Comment: The sensible thing to do would be to fix the permissions on the share such that the owner remains set to the user account that put the file there.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew as your hint gave me what I needed. After your comment I did some digging and found that my share settings where not correct. Setting the folder share permissions to full control by everyone and administrator group fixed the issue (then we lock the folder down in the security tab). Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly, you could embed the owner's email as an alternate data stream into the file. Read [this link here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx).

And with a few powershell scripts, you could write the job owner into the file at submit time and extract it out on the remote machine at run time.

I believe the alternate data stream survives the command line `copy` command as long as NTFS is used everywhere as the filesystem.